# Prevent sidebar menu from scrolling below footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky-footer

I have a p

And the css:

```
.sidebar-menu {
    float: right; 
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
    
}

.sidebar-content {
    color: #5bc5f2; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    position: fixed;
        top: 75px;
    
}
```

Currently, the sidebar menu is sticked to the top with 80px (thats fine) and basicly I want it to stop scrolling when reaching some certain point. Any help?

Comment: can you add your code with jsfiddle?

Comment: i cannot getting your answer. do you want to hide sidebar when page near to footer??

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("scroll",function () {
        if (parseInt($(this).scrollTop()) > $("footer").offset().top-500) {
    $(".sidebar-menu").removeClass("fixed");
    $(".sidebar-menu").hide();
} else {
    $(".sidebar-menu").addClass("fixed");
   $(".sidebar-menu").show();
}}
```

Comment: did you remove the fixed position from the navbar? just apply the fixed position with that class

Comment: can i add another answer cuz i cant explain here

Comment: @Araz If this doesn't answer the question, don't add another one. Edit this answer because it could be downvoted or even deleted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("scroll",function () {
    var offsetToTop = parseInt($(this).scrollTop());
        if (offsetToTop > $("footer").offset().top-500) {
    $(".sidebar-menu").removeClass("fixed");
    $(".sidebar-menu").addClass("absolute");
    $(".sidebar-menu").css("top",offsetToTop)  
} else {
    $(".sidebar-menu").addClass("fixed");
    $(".sidebar-menu").removeClass("absolute");
    $(".sidebar-menu").removeAttr("style");
}}
```

in the absolute class just make the position absolute.

Comment: ok see my prevois answer when you remove fixed class just $("sidenav").hide() and on the other side just make it $("sidenav").show()